# How do I find the equation of a vector which passes through two points and crosses the xy plane?

Tags: vectors

We have got a question like this:
[image]

We are somewhat clueless on how to solve this.

The nearest we got is:

$OA = 3i + 4j +k$ and $AB = -i-7j+4k$.

Then, the equation is:

$3i + 4j +k +t(-i-7j+4k)$.

How do we use the $xy$ plane crossing feature to solve the above?

Comment: You should need to make sure that your x_3 coordinate of your direction vector is not equal to 0. Then it automatically passes the xy-plane

Comment: @Théophile Yes, we know that. Simply put the image of that question. The question was from a question bank .pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

Setting $z=0$ we get the equation $$0=1+4t$$ thus $$t=-\frac{1}{4}$$ and we get
$$x=\frac{13}{4}$$ and $$y=\frac{23}{4}$$

Comment: So, there is *no* correct answer among the given choices?

Comment: or there is a typo